# Select fields which contain only numeric values ACCESS

Tags: ms-access

Can you please help me with these two points? :
(1) I working on Access and would like to wirte a query that returns those fields that contain only numberic values. e.g., 12, 45, 67. It shoud exclude any fields such as 12T, abc, TT34 because they contain characters in addition to the numbers.

(2) will it be possible to write a query to return data from fields with the following format: Num Num Char.   such as : 19K  or 30H  or 22U

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an expression such as:

```
WHERE Field Like "[0-9][0-9][a-z]"
```

Which will return two numbers followed by a letter, or

```
WHERE IsNumeric([Field])=True
```

Which will return numeric fields.

Comment: Is there any method to do this that would use indexes?